# Save dynamic query to variable in postgres stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamicquery

I have the following postgres stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
schema.MyProcedure()
AS $$

DECLARE 
    RowCount int;
    
BEGIN
    
    SELECT cnt INTO RowCount 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM MySchema.MyTable
        ) AS sub;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'RowCount: %', RowCount;
    
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which "prints" out the row count of the static table MySchema.MyTable. How can it make it so I pass the Table and Schema name as an input.

eg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
schema.MyProcedure(MySchema_In varchar, MyTable_In varchar)
AS $$

DECLARE 
    RowCount int;
    
BEGIN
    
    SELECT cnt INTO RowCount 
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM || **MySchema_In** || . || **MyTable_In** || 
        ) AS sub;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'RowCount: %', RowCount;
    
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: 1)  You can simplify this with ` Select count(*)  into RowCount ...` and eliminate the sub-query 2) Look at [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `format()` instead of concatenating the strings with `||` and then [`EXECUTE ... INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to get the query's result, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(MySchema_In varchar, MyTable_In varchar)
AS $$
DECLARE RowCount int;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT count(*) FROM %I.%I',$1,$2) INTO RowCount;
  RAISE NOTICE 'RowCount: %', RowCount;    
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```